# How can i install scikit-image module for Python on Windows properly?

Tags: python, pip, scikit-image

Platform: Windows 10 Pro 20H2, Python 3.8.7

I need to install `image-match` module, but when install is coming to required `scikit-image` module, i am recieving error:

```
Running setup.py install for scikit-image ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
```

Surfing Internet i found out that `scikit-image` module wheel for windows is not available. I tried to install `scikit-image` with binary .whl file. Looks like module installed and i tried to install `image-match` again. Now i am recieving this:

```
Building wheel for image-match (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for image-match: filename=image_match-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl size=21230 sha256=bb2a55e18dac36ab10056523f66383756fac637eafe4f12d4e12df9a3da3ad8c
Stored in directory: c:\users\user\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\70\62\40\3511b893ee0655b25176450c3b0405caf4ded0f44927de3ebe
Building wheel for scikit-image (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
Partial import of skimage during the build process.
```

I am not that good in Python, so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install directly from Github Link for some reason PyPI has an older version of the branch.
Use this Command `pip install git+https://github.com/EdjoLabs/image-match`